# Trimming decimal numbers for coordinates/heights in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, calculate-values, precision, numbering

I have a GeoPackage table with coordinates and heights. I only want 3 decimals for the coordinates and 2 decimals for the heights.

In the past I could easily define the precision in the field calculator, but the field is greyed out for GeoPackage layers. It only works for temporary layers.

I also tried ["Refactor field"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#refactor-fields) tools and defined the precision, but it gave me the table you are seeing in the screenshot.

If it was string I could use a the `substr()` function. But these are numeric fields. And copying to a new string field, using `substr()` function and copying back to numeric is too much manual work, as I run into this task frequently.

[image]

Comment: Because as soon as you save it as a permanent geopackage layer, you are back to the situation of having many decimals... round() is doing the trick perfectly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When creating a field containing a decimal number, use [`round(yourexpression,x)`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#round), with `x` being the number of decimals you want to have.

Answer (score 5):

If no rounding effect should be applied then you simply create a new field and filling it with values from original field with doubles, see image below.

[image: result]

Mind that in this case precision should be adjusted appropriately.

---

Another option without rounding effect can be achieved using several String Functions: [`left()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#left), [`strpos()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#strpos), and [`substr()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#substr)

```
left("float", strpos("float", '.') - 1)
|| '.'|| 
substr("float", strpos("float", '.') + 1, 3)
```

And get the output like

[image: result2]

If the length of values before comma always posses the same length, then you may simply use [`left()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#left) accordingly, e.g `left("float",4)`.