# Why can't I change precision of decimal number in new Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, calculate-values, precision, numbering

Can't click those fields. It worked in the past and now just don't. I can't figure it out.

[image: The problem.]

And even it's set to three by default (and I can't change that), it ends up being infinite.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`round()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#round) function in the expression to limit the decimals to 3 digits:

```
round($area,3)
```

Without round:
[image]

With round:
[image]

Comment: For more details please also check this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387701/trimming-decimal-numbers-for-coordinates-heights-in-qgis