Convert to rounded numeric from scientific notation in QGIS using refactor
A commercial software exports shapefile with several attributes (of datatype double) and in some cases these values are too small like 10 to power -8 (e-8).
I do not need such precision and I am happy with precision of 4.
Is there any tool in QGIS that allows to format these small numbers to precision 3 or 4?
I tried refactor tool in QGIS, but even after changing the precision on “double” attributes, I do not get required precision.
Anything I miss or is there another way to do this in QGIS?

Try to use round() function in the field calculator. Here is an example: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/397031/63384

What are the data types/formats of these fields? e.g. 4e-8 as string? Or 0.00000004 as double?

they are all double. I have to do this for numerous files and was contemplating making a graphical model. In graphical model, it is probably easier to use refactor than a round ? I am just surprised that refactor has no effect.
