# QGIS Geopackage decimal field: cannot adjust Field Length and Precision

Tags: qgis, geopackage

At 3.20.3, when creating a Decimal number (real) Geopackage field, the options to modify the *Field Length* and *Precision* are greyed out, as shown in the screenshot below.

However, *Field Length* and *Precision* are **not** greyed out when using File Geodatabase or Shapefile tables, so the issue appears to be unique to Geopackages.

Related questions have asked for workarounds to limit the resulting number of decimal places (for example [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387701/trimming-decimal-numbers-for-coordinates-heights-in-qgis)).

However, I am asking *why* the inability to modify *Field Length* and *Precision* is unique to Geopackage tables?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found [the developer answer](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6730#no1) which explains that it is not implemented for GeoPackage, since field width and precision are not part of the GeoPackage standard.

Comment: I've accepted your answer (thanks!), but I don't understand your last sentence.  For example what does "...now put down..." mean?

Comment: Thank you. I meant the developer refused to fix this issue and has closed the topic. Specific details are on the link that I've attached to my answer.

Comment: @Ash, I've edited your answer so paraphrase the reason (since SE suggests answers be standalone and not dependent on information in external links). I've also edited out the "put down" wording, since it seems to be phrasing that is not globally used. (However, I also upvoted your answer since it gave the info needed, if indirectly).